# Overloading [ ] with a template type

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary

I have a class that takes 2 template types, one for key (K) and one for value (V).

When trying to overload square brackets, I get an error saying "no operator "[]" matches these operands.

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class MyMap
{
    KeyPair<K, V>* Pairs;
    int Count = 0;

public:
    MyMap()
    {
        Pairs = new KeyPair<K, V>[100];
    }

    V& operator[] (const K& key)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        {
            if (key == Pairs[i].Key)
            {
                return Pairs[i].Value;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then when trying to use it in main...

```
MyMap<string, int>* myMap = new MyMap<string, int>();  

// This gives me a "no operator "[]" matches these operands.
cout << myMap["hello"] << endl;
```

I have read a lot of other solutions where they know the type for the key, but is it possible to use a template type of a key when overloading like this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you considered using `std::vector<KeyPair<K,V>>` instead?

Comment: What is the type of `myMap`!? Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong, your example is insufficient. Notably, we have no idea what `myMap`'s type is. These types of questions should include a [MCVE] that produces the mentioned error.

Comment: You may want to consider changing `V& operator[] (const K key)` to `V& operator[] (const K & key)` as the original way will cause a copy of `K` every time. Since it appears you are using a string type as a key, copies may become expensive. You may also want to look into `const V& operator[] (const K & key) const` to support [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).

Comment: You can't invoke `V::operator[]` like that on a pointer-to-V. Try `(*myMap)["hello"]`, and then switch to a local (non-pointer) variable or a reference.

Comment: Thanks all, sorry for the crap code example. Removing the dynamic memory allocation allowed it to work (thanks Francois).    MyMap<string, int> myMap;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyMap<string, int>* myMap = new MyMap<string, int>();
```

`myMap` here is a **pointer**. You meant:

```
cout << (*myMap)["hello"] << endl;
```

As [oisyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8951473/oisyn) noted, `operator[]` must be made `public` as well.

---

Also:

- Don't use raw `new`/`delete`. Use smart pointers.

  - Actually, you probably don't need to allocate. Just create the map on the stack.
- You're unnecessarily copying the key in your `operator[]`. Take it by `const&`.

Comment: And then you'll probably get an error explaining that `operator[]` is inaccessible, because MyMap has no public methods.

Comment: I feel a superior alternative would be to just use value semantics and avoid the unnecessary dynamic allocation entirely. `MyMap<string, int> myMap;` would do just fine.

Comment: Sorry for my crap example code. I tried (*myMap)["hello"] but it didn't work. Changing to Francois' example worked (MyMap<string, int> myMap;).. thank you!